# Get program traces with JaCoCo

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, jacoco

Looking to retrieve program traces using JaCoCo, on a Maven project in IntelliJ. The overall point is to get as much control flow graph information as possible using JaCoCo, but I understand it might not be fully possible (unless I am incorrect).

The JaCoCo version is 0.8.11, the test coverage is set up and working fine.

The only suggested solution I recieved was to add a JaCoCo's Java agent to my JVM options, but IntelliJ official website suggests strongly against that, so I am looking for verification and/or alternative solutions. Any advie will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look: https://blog.soebes.io/posts/2023/10/2023-10-26-maven-jacoco-configuration/

Comment: You can choose the coverage runner in the menu File Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Coverage to JaCoCo, however, this is somehow hardcoded by IDEA, it's OK to set up your own JaCoCo runner by using Maven Plugin, then use the menu "Run -> Show Coverage Data..." and open your Jacoco output file in IDEA.

Comment: Thank you both. I checked out both possible solutions but no success. I need to rephrase the question to be honest